# NPM Install Error - Msnodesql

Tags: sql-server, node.js, npm, windows-server-2012

I'm running npm to install msnodesql, an npm library for sql server drivers. I am installing this on a Windows Server 2012 box.

I have installed Visual C++ 2010, node-gyp and Python 2.7.x.x as dependencies, and all of these installs were successful.

When I run npm install msnodesql, I get a big red error:

> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Miscrosoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7):
>   error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'sqlserver.vcxproj' is
>   invalid. Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you
>   are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have
>   specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

My box is 64-bit. Not too experienced in this stuff at all, so though it looks like a platform error, i'm really not sure what to do.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error. Turns out I needed to remove my installed node.js (64 bit) and download 32-bit node.js instead. Once I did this I ran node-gyp configure, then node-gyp build with no errors.